# Inserting custom element, attribute gets stripped

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I made a tinymce fiddle about this problem: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/O0gaab

I add a custom element "custom-block" and a custom plugin to insert that element.

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('custom', function(editor, url) {
    editor.addButton('custom', {
      text: 'CUSTOM',
      onclick: function() {
        // Open window
        editor.windowManager.open({
          title: 'Custom plugin',
          body: [
            {type: 'textbox', name: 'src', label: 'SRC'},
            {type: 'label', name: 'title', text: 'Insert content bellow:'},
            {type: 'textbox', name: 'content', multiline: true, style: 'width:500px;height:100px;'}
          ],
          onsubmit: function(e) {
            console.log(e.data);
            editor.insertContent('<custom-block src="' + e.data.src + '">' + e.data.content + '</custom-block>');
          }
        });
      }
    });
});
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste custom"
    ],
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | custom",
    //valid_elements: "+*[*]", //when using this option trying to allow everything get an error "Cannot read property 'src' of undefined"
    extend_valid_elements: "custom-block[src]",
    custom_elements: "custom-block"
});
```

The element, get inserted correctly but without the `src` attribute.

From the documentation I though that `extend_valid_elements: "custom-block[src]"` would allow `src` attribute on a `custom-block` but it gets stripped everytime.

I also tried to set `valid_elements` to everything(`+*[*]`) just in case, but then gets worse because at inserting, I get an error: *"Cannot read property 'src' of undefined"*.

I am making any mistake or what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The name of the configuration option is `extended_valid_elements` so you simply named it wrong in your configuration.  It should be:

```
extended_valid_elements: "custom-block[src]"
```

I have updated your fiddle (http://fiddle.tinymce.com/O0gaab/1) and things appear to work.